# Are those historical portrayal 100% or mostly real?

Tags: historical-accuracy, cosmos-spacetime-odyssey

[Cosmos: A Spacetime Odyssey Tv SHOW](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395695/)

A great deep view with simple way into our discoveries & inventions so far. In this series Neil deGrasse Tyson explained many things about time and space. And sometimes they show animated presentations of historical characters like Newton or Willian Herschel etc. They showed some events too through animated representations.

Question is : are those real events? or imagination to simply present things?

In S01E04 Neil deGrasse Tyson said

> Back in 1802, on a night like this,
>
> the astronomer William Herschel strolled the beach
>
> on the English coast, with his son John.

In S01E05 an animated presentation showed that Newton was discovering something using light and got distracted and didn't experimented on it ever.

> (knocking on door, door opens)
>
> Begging your pardon, Master Newton,
>
> the cook frets that your dinner will spoil, sir.
>
> DEGRASSE TYSON: No, Isaac, don't< put the magnifying glass down!
>
> Something even more amazing is hidden in the light
>
> a code, a key to the cosmos.
>
> Isaac Newton didn't miss much, but that one was a beauty.
>
> He just walked right past the door
>   to a hidden universe;
>
> a door that would not swing open again for another 150 years.

So after watching these 2 segments it came to my mind that there are more animated incidents that are shown in this series. Which either portray a conversation between 2 or may be some incident that led to a discovery.

How accurate are they? I mean Newton didn't wrote "I was doing something, suddenly butler knocked ....... " etc. right!!

Does anyone know are these **presentation/event/conversations of historical characters** all imagination or real or real to which extent?

Comment: Good question.  But maybe better asked elsewhere.  Doesn't "Cosmos" have its own site?  Or at least Twitter & Instagram accounts...

Comment: If those scenes aren't documented somehow, I'd be surprised. I can't imagine NDT being OK presenting non-factual information. My guess is that the event happened but they're guessing at the actual scene.

Comment: Back in those days, before there were phones and email, and when traveling wasn't as easy as today, scientists, like other people, wrote letters to stay in touch with friends, family and colleagues (and tell them stuff about their lives). - In case of Newton, there is e.g. __[The Newton Project](http://www.newtonproject.sussex.ac.uk/prism.php?id=1)__, where they have a big collection of letters he wrote.

Comment: @Catija - Actually, NDT has been caught making inaccurate historical statements both in Cosmos and outside. His science is much much better than his history.

Comment: @SystemDown "NDT has been caught making inaccurate historical statements both in Cosmos and outside" really? can you please provide any link for that? Or mention any news. Curious

Comment: @AtanuCSE - For instance, he is often quoted saying that the Islamic age of science ended because of the advent of the anti-philosophical movement spearheaded by Al Ghazzali, whereas academic historians believe that this is a far too simplistic a view to take. So take the history with a healthy grain of salt. His science however is much better. Still should be taken with a grain of salt (that's the scientific way after all), but is far more accurate.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Nope I didn't found any website. I searched before asking for some clue about this. And I literally don't think I could have asked this question in 140 letters